# Object Comparison Using IEquatable Fails

Tags: c#

I have custom objects which implements IEquatable so that I can use List.Contains(anotherCustomObject). So that if it contains the object remove it from the list.

The issues is that my implemented .Equals isn't working as expected and a few but now all is showing up as not equal and isn't being removed from the List.

To clarify, in the image below currentSpecs is the list that I want to remove from if it contains any from tmpAS400Specs.

[image]

Below is the code.

```
var tmpSpecs = new AS400SpecificationAttribute
{
    ProductNumber = workTask.WIITEM,
    AttributeGroup = attrGroup,
    AttributeName = attrName,
    AttributeValue = attrValue
};

if (currentSpecs.Contains(tmpSpecs))
{
    currentSpecs.Remove(tmpSpecs);
}
```

**Code for compare**

```
public class AS400SpecificationAttribute : IEquatable<AS400SpecificationAttribute>
{
    private string name;
    private string value;
    private string group;
    private string productNumber;


    public string ProductNumber
    {
        get { return productNumber; }
        set
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                productNumber = value.Trim().ToUpper();
        }
    }

    public string AttributeName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                this.name = value.Trim();
        }
    }
    public string AttributeValue
    {
        get
        {
            return this.value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                this.value = value.Trim().Replace("\\\"","\"");
        }
    }
    public string AttributeGroup
    {
        get
        {
            return this.group;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                this.group = value.Trim();
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(AS400SpecificationAttribute other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;
        return this.ProductNumber.Equals(other.productNumber) 
          && ((this.group != null && this.group.Equals(other.AttributeGroup)) 
            || (this.group == null && other.AttributeGroup == null)) 
          && ((this.name!= null && this.name.Equals(other.AttributeName)) 
            || (this.name == null && other.AttributeName == null)) 
          && ((this.value != null && this.value.Equals(other.AttributeValue)) 
            || (this.value == null && other.AttributeName == null)); 
    }
}
```

Why is the comparison not able to detect that the two attributes are the same?

Comment: Seems you're missing some parenthesis in there, the inner parenthesis is somewhat like this: `((a && b) || c && d)` Shouldn't the `c && d` be inside a parenthesis as well? `((this.group != null && this.group.Equals(other.AttributeGroup)) || this.group == null && other.AttributeGroup == null)`

Comment: Can you show us full class at least properties implementations?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen True fixed but not  the main problem, still encountered error.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria Yes sir!

Comment: "error"? You're not mentioning any error here, you just said the comparison didn't work, which I took to mean that you got "not equal" when expected "equal", or vice versa. Can you elaborate on this error you're getting?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The error isn't related to the Exception class. The error is that even though the Debugger looks like the two attributes are equal the comparison is false. There is something wrong with it but I am unable to see it so I ask for your help.

Comment: Yes, so obviously your comparison method says "false" when you expect it to say "true".

Comment: Yeah well does it look like it should say false instead of true based on class implementation and .equals implementation?

Comment: You sure there isn't any hidden odd spaces in there, like "non breakable space" or something like that instead of a normal space?

Comment: Does the debugger hit your comparison method? My understanding of `.Contains()`  could be wrong but I suspect that it's not actually comparing the items in the list and just checking that one of the item references is the reference you're checking for.

Comment: @MaxSorin Other references in that list are being removed refer to image 17 vs 2 left over.

Comment: `List<T>.Contains` uses `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` which in turn will use `IEquatable<T>` when implemented - http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,324

Comment: Try make it case insensitive. Object A.value = 'x', Object B.value = 'X'

Comment: @ChrisWohlert That is the answer I suspect. Missed that, good eyes on you man :) Specifically, Chris is referring to the `3" x 5"` values which has a lowercase `x` in one of the objects and an uppercase `X` in the other, this makes the comparison say they're different, which according to the rules implemented, they are.

Comment: Or, on the other hand, now that you know there *is* a difference, perhaps they shouldn't be removed as duplicates?

Comment: Well, don't feel bad about that. Getting equality checks correct is sometimes an exercise in patience and now you've likely uncovered a form of bug, either in the data gathering part, or in the specification for your equality check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed this:

`Object A.value = 'x', Object B.value = 'X'.`

Try making it case insensitive, or make sure your objects are truly equal.

Answer (score 0):

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var other = obj as AS400SpecificationAttribute;
    if (other == null)
```

... etc.

Comment: `List<T>` uses `IEquatable<T>` when it is implemented since it uses `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`.

Comment: I think it would be nice to elaborate on that answer.